# How to set the release date of a post in SharePoint?

Tags: web-part, date-time, user-controls, content

We wish to post something to the SharePoint website, e.g. an announcement, a calendar schedule, etc. But we **do not** want users to see those posts until the release date. Is there a way to set accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Scheduling Start date to the list, While retrieving the post, show the post where the current date > start date

Comment: yes, you can configure a view, with parameters Shiva said. And on website add webpart of announcemens list and change the view to created before.

Comment: +1 Thanks folks. It is so cool! For items created with **Announce Date** in the future, which means those items are hidden for now. How to "see" those items and edit them? (Changing back to **Show all items in this view** is not convenience, and not logical.)